# How to reload stunnel configuration with command line?

Tags: stunnel

Is there a command line to reload stunnel configuration file when the stunnel is running?

I start stunnel by command line. But I don't find any methods that can dynamic change its configuration.

Edit:

According [here](https://www.stunnel.org/sdf_ChangeLog.html) of Version 5.15, 2015.04.16, urgency: LOW:

**New commandline options "-reload" to reload the configuration file and "-reopen" to reopen the log file of stunnel running as a Windows service (thanks to Marc McLaughlin).**

It seems already have the command line, but I couldn't reload it.

Is my step wrong?

My test steps as following.

1. Enter dos  mod
2. c:\stunnel\stunnel.exe -start
3. change the stunnel.config
4. c:\stunnel\stunnel.exe -reload

I only saw the stunnel pop-out window at step 4. But it does not reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How stupid I am, I found I use an older version stunnel.

It works when I change the to version 5.25.